# Welcher Modus nach "Angenommen, …" im mathematischen Kontext?

Tags: subjunctive, mathematics, grammatical-mood

[Indirekte Beweise](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) in der Mathematik werden häufig mit *"Angenommen, …"* eingeleitet, um die angenommene Aussage später auf einen Widerspruch zu führen.

Ich stelle mir die Frage, ob innerhalb der Annahme das Verb im Indikativ, im Konjunktiv I oder sogar im Konjunktiv II stehen sollte. Ich habe alle drei Varianten schon gesehen, allerdings bin ich mir unsicher welche am gebräuchlisten bzw. am "korrektesten" ist, oder ob es sogar Unterschiede in der Bedeutung gibt.

Beispiel:

> Angenommen, √2 **ist** rational. Dann […]

> Angenommen, √2 **sei** rational. Dann […]

> Angenommen, √2 **wäre** rational. Dann […]

Für mich klingt der Konjunktiv I hier am natürlichsten.

Answer (score 1):

In älteren Mathe-Lehrbüchern finde ich "angenommen, ... sei". In neueren Texten findet man auch "angenommen, ... ist".

> Sei √2 eine rationale Zahl.

Diese Formulierung habe ich so in keinem Lehrbuch gefunden. Man findet natürlich regelmäßig Aussagen wie:

> Sei x eine rationale Zahl.

Hierbei definiert man, was eine Variable darstellen soll. √2 ist aber definiert (und zwar als die positive Zahl, die mit sich selbst multipliziert 2 ergibt). Ich kann zwar annehmen, √2 sei rational, und diese Aussage logisch zum Widerspruch führen (reductio ad absurdum), aber ich kann nicht definieren, dass √2 rational ist.

Comment: Das trifft nicht ganz meine Frage. Dass man bei Definitionen üblicherweise zu Formulierungen mit *"[Es] Sei …"* (Jussiv) greift, ist mir klar. Meine Frage bezieht sich allerdings ausschließlich auf Annahmen, bei denen gerade nichts definiert wird, sondern die Gültigkeit einer (unwahren) Aussage *angenommen* wird.

Answer (score 0):

Gottlieb Frege wäre stolz auf diese Frage. Da Mathematiker Jargon sprechen, der nicht unbedingt einheitlich ist, kann es auch keine allemgemeingültige Antwort auf die allgemeine Frage geben, welchen Modus die Konjunktion *angenommen* regiere. Tatsächlich sind die Vereinfachungen, die die Schulgrammatik regelmäßig annimmt, nicht zu halten.

Da "sei" in der Sprache der Mathematiker ohnehin eine anzunehmende Vorraussetzung ausdrückt, ist dies sicherlich nicht falsch. Das ist *Optativ* wie bspw. *“Lass uns nicht streiten”*, vgl. engl. *let* (sinngemäß "sei").

> Sei *x* eine rationale Zahl.

Das Partizip *Angenommem* spielt dafür keine entscheidende Rolle. Es betrift im Kern den Unterschied zwischen hochdeutschen Partizipien, *Anzunehmen sei*, und Niederdeutschem (bspw. Friedrich Gauß), wo der Infinitiv an gleicher steht, der hochdeutsch nominalisiert werden kann: *Deutsch (zu) sprechen ist nicht ein Fach*. Letztendlich ist ein Unterschied in der Lautung *Annehmen*, *Annahme*, *An(g)enommen* vermutlich auf einundieselbe Wendung zurückzuführen, *Antithese* aber nur über niederdeutsch mit *ent-* zu *an zu* zu führen. Das hochdeutsche Partizip mit *ge-* ist jedenfalls kein eindeutiger Faktor. Dementsprechend ist auch das Existenzverb nicht einwandfrei.

Aus didaktischer Sicht sowie dialektisch kommt es also auf die Zielgruppe an, das vorhandene Verständnis und den Zweck.

Answer (score 0):

In der Induktion der mathematischen Beweise ist *während* des Schrittes von n auf n+1 die Vermutung wahr, da vorausgesetzt wird, dass fűr kleine n bereits der Beweis vorliegt oder noch folgt. Es handelt sich also nicht um den in der Alltagssprache űblicheren Fall, daß űber den Wahrheitsgehalt nichts sicher bekannt ist. Und dies ist dann die Grundlage fűr die Benutzung des Indikativ. (Und in der Regel wird der Beweis ja erbracht...)

Comment: Die Annahme eines Widerspruchsbeweises und die Induktionsvoraussetzung eines Induktionsbeweises unterscheiden sich in der Bedeutung. Bei Ersterem wird eine (unwahre) Aussage angenommen, die insbesondere gar nicht bewiesen wurde. Bei Zweiterem wird eine Aussage vorausgesetzt, deren Gültigkeit zuvor bewiesen wurde. Diese hat vielmehr die Form einer Definition (*"Es sei …"*).

Answer (score -1):

Was nach "angenommen" kommt, ist grammatikalisch eine indirekte Rede - und die stehen im Konjunktiv - auch wenn diese Regel öfter bezweifelt wird und in der Umgangssprache der Indikativ schleichend Einzug hält.

Bleibt also die Frage, welcher der beiden Konjunktive: der des Präsens oder der des Präteritums (den manche auch "Konjunktiv II" oder, vermutlich am treffendsten, *Irrealis* nennen.

Grundsätzlich ist der Konjunktiv Präsens (oder Konjunktiv I) korrekt:

> Es ist so.
> Angenommen, es *sei* so.

Allerdings kann man auch den *Irrealis* verwenden - nämlich dann, wenn man das, was man sagt, selbst nicht glaubt:

> Angenommen, es *wäre* so, dann müßte *das* gleich *dem* sein, was es aber nicht ist, deshalb *ist* es nicht so.

Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Arten des Konjunktiv ist die Einstellung des Sprechers zu der Aussage, die er mitteilt:

> Angenommen, es *sei* ...

Das kann so sein oder auch nicht, dazu habe ich erstmal keine Meinung zu äußern.

> Angenommen, es *wäre* ...

Das gebe ich zwar wieder, aber ich halte es selbst nicht für wahr/richtig.

Ich habe schon öfter in dem Zusammenhang Schillers "Wallenstein" zitiert, auf ein Neues:

> Mir meldet er aus Linz er *läge* krank;

Frage: glaubt Wallenstein das? Antwort: *wenn* er das geglaubt hätte oder zumindest der Aussage neutral gegenübergestanden hätte, dann hätte er gesagt "... er *liege* krank". Tatsächlich aber:

> Doch hab' ich sichre Nachricht, daß er sich
> Zu Frauenberg versteckt beim Grafen Gallas.
> Nimm beide fest und schick' sie mir hierher.

Glaubt er das? Wohl eher nicht.

Comment: "*Was nach "angenommen" kommt, ist grammatikalisch eine indirekte Rede […]"* – Kannst du das belegen? Ich zweifel es nicht an, aber würde es gerne nachvollziehen.